# Which data to remove when adding new data to a full cache

Tags: memory, computer-science

I am trying to understand the data transfer in computer cache.

Talking about computer catch, When new data is added to a cache that's already full, some of the data must be removed.
Anyone can discribe a good way to decide which data to evict?

Comment: The term is `cache`, not `catch` (the latter which evokes images of the baseball season which is about to begin).  One option for deciding which data should be removed is to use a queue structure, where the eldest entries are booted when new entries must be inserted and there be no existing space for them.

Comment: Oh, thanks. yes it's correct

Answer (score 1):

If there is no room in the cache, the oldest data is removed from the cache to make room.

> One option for deciding which data should be removed is to use a queue
>   structure, where the eldest entries are booted when new entries must
>   be inserted and there be no existing space for them. – Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Nice answer.  I could not have said it better myself :-)